# Foundation dropdown (with Plunker)

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I've been following along with [this guide from Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/javascript.html), but I've been unable to get this simple dropdown to work.

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nMqBGEjOvhVtaWFIIQHD

I've done the following:

1. Included JQuery above Foundation's JS
2. Included Foundation's JS
3. Initialized Foundation in the `<body>` via `<script>$(document).foundation();
   </script>`
4. Did not note any JS errors in console.

Yet, when I click the dropdown, nothing happens. What am I missing here? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need anything further.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the guide:

> "We recommend that you initialize Foundation at the end of the page"
>   .

like this:

```
...
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HPO0Be5eAOCDp2QXs8b8?p=preview)**

Comment: Ah, the recommendation is a requirement I see ;-) Thanks, this solved my issue. Could have sworn I tested it this way.